# How to get status code from websocket upgrade request with socket.io client

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have rewritten the upgrade event listener in node.js like this:

```
server.on('upgrade', (req, socket, head) => {
  socket.write('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n\r\n');
  socket.destroy();

  return;
}
```

How can I get the response code 401 from client side (I use socket.io-client) ?

The error response only shows `Error: websocket error`.

```
socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Short answer is you cannot. Long answer, check this almost identical question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762596/how-to-read-status-code-from-rejected-websocket-opening-handshake-with-javascrip

Answer (score 0):

> socket.on('error', function(err) {
> console.log(err);
> });

Comment: The `error` event only on `io` object, `socket.io.on("error", (error) => { //... });` and It also shows noting.

Answer (score 0):

`socket.write / socket.destroy`  are from other websocket library (https://github.com/websockets/ws) not socket.io.

Using socket.io-client u cant listen to disconnections with this listener:

```
socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
  // ...
});
```

and on server side you can just disconnect like this

```
socket.disconnect()
```

Comment: The socket is `net.Socket` from node `Net` module, check the [doc](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/http.html#http_event_upgrade).